# Trying to run plt.show() creates error message

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

executing the command 'plt.show()' shows the following error message: 'Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)'.

I updated all my packages and after that, i always got the above-mentioned error message. Downgrading the matplotlib version to a lower one could not solve the issue. If I remove the command 'plt.show()', it'll work properly.

Can anyone help me?

Here is the examplary code that I try to run:

```
xpoints = np.array([1, 8])
ypoints = np.array([3, 10])

plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints)
plt.show()
```

Comment: ['Process finished with exit code "1073741819" python site: stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%27Process+finished+with+exit+code+%221073741819%22+python+site%3A+stackoverflow.com&rlz=1C1ONGR_enUS976US976&sxsrf=AOaemvJHjul2IBjHMWGjLx8o59RMN9oX4g%3A1635765934197&ei=rs5_Yb6sC6HJ0PEPsIOHuAc&oq=%27Process+finished+with+exit+code+%221073741819%22+python+site%3A+stackoverflow.com&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFQjwhYjwhgwRtoAXAAeACAAW-IAW-SAQMwLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwi-u8X7hvfzAhWhJDQIHbDBAXcQ4dUDCA8&uact=5) seems to be a generic error code related to PyCharm issues.

Comment: This is also the error code I received when working on the issue in the duplicate over the weekend, which is why I closed the question to the duplicate. The error occurs when trying to plot after updating `conda` (base) or an environment.